# Кодирование списков в векторы нулей и единиц

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Вот код

```
import numpy as np
test = [[5,4,5,3,4,9,7,4,1,5,7,0,5,6],
        [4,3,5,5,3,4,9,7,4,1,5,7,0,5],
        [4,3,5,5,3,4,9,7,4,1,5,7,0,5],
        [4,3,5,5,3,4,9,7,4,1,5,7,0,5]]

results = np.zeros((len(test), 14))

for i, sequence in enumerate(test):
    print(i)
    print(sequence)
    print( results[i, sequence])
    results[i, sequence] =1
    print( results[i, sequence])
    print()


print(results)
```

вывод на Экран

```
0
[5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 1, 5, 7, 0, 5, 6]
#results до изменения 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#results после изменения
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

1
[4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 1, 5, 7, 0, 5]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

2
[4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 1, 5, 7, 0, 5]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

3
[4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9, 7, 4, 1, 5, 7, 0, 5]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

[[1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

почему финальный results выглядит так:

```
     [[1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Там же должны быть одни единицы(1.)

Comment: "Там же должны быть одни единицы" - с чего вдруг?

Comment: print( results[i, sequence])
    results[i, sequence] =1
    print( results[i, sequence])

#results до изменения 
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
#results после изменения
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

Так я проверял. 
Скорее всего я делаю очень тупую ошибку, но если вас не затруднит могли бы вы сказать, почему так выходит.

Comment: К какому элементу идет обращение в ``results[i, sequence]``? (где ``sequence`` - список).

Comment: к results, к каждому массиву

Comment: Вы можете пояснить что вы хотите получить? Может вы хотите сделать `One-Hot-Encoding`?

Comment: я читаю книгу Deep lerning и там был такой пример

Comment: Обращение к каждому массиву идет через ``results[i]``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если рядом со строкой
    results[i, sequence] =1
вы выведите значения самих `i` и `sequence`, то увидите, что обрабатываются не все элементы, а только те, номера которых содержатся в массиве test.

Например, для i=0 это будут 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 и 9, соответственно элементы с индексами 2, 8, 10, 11, 12 и 13 не обрабатываются и остаются нулевыми.

Comment: Сделал еще пару примеров и оказалось, что все очень просто. спасибо